# Problems with adding 4port usb hub to Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: usb, hub

I'm attempting to replicate this [Raspberry Pi Zero USB-Hub](http://frederickvandenbosch.be/?p=1343) . . .

There is a slight difference with the hub I'm working with though. It is the type that is not powered externally. My problem is that I cannot get a data connection from the hub. It powers on (the status led turns on and plugged in optical mice turn on) but there is no data. Is my problem due to the fact that the USB hub is un-powered or is there something else that I'm missing in the equation?

From what I have tested the hub works fine when plugged into a laptop, or over the OTG port of the RPi Zero but when attached via the test pads it fails to operate correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apparently one of the pads is notoriously prone to shorting as it is very close to the bottom side of the through hole of the micro USB OTG port. This was what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

Did you attach it to the power testpads as well? With 5V and ground connected it should have every power it needs.